# I am able to draw the box but I am not able to remove it! (Canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mootools

I have asked this question before and it seemed that the code I was using was pretty confusing. So this is a virtually dumed down version of the same code. 
I draw a square on the canvas using the add function. Like wise I should be able to remove the item from the canvas using the remove function! Alas it doesn't seem to happen so.

Here is the code

```
$(window).addEvent('load',function(){


CANVAS.init({ canvasElement : 'canvas' });
CANVAS.layers.add( new Layer({
    id : 'myLayer'
}));

var colors = [
    'rgba(255,0,0,1)',
    ];

var pos = [
    { x: 150, y : 100 },
]

       var foo = new CanvasItem({
        id : 'item',
        x : pos[0].x,
        y : pos[0].y,
        fillStyle : colors[0],
        events : {
            onDraw : function(ctx)
            {
                ctx.fillStyle = this.fillStyle;
                ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,200,200);
            }
        }
    });

CANVAS.layers.get('myLayer').add(foo);
CANVAS.draw();
CANVAS.layers.get('myLayer').remove(foo);
CANVAS.draw();
    });
```

It can also be seen here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WRRns/4/)

The library I am using to implement this is via mootools canvas library. [Here is the link of the functions.](http://forvar.de/js/mcl/docs.Layer.html#fn-remove)

Hopefully this will help people get my query. Feel free to ask questions if you are still pondering about what exactly is my problem! Thanks

EDIT : There is a bug in the library. Please find the link to the corrected code below in the comments of the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error in the library was in the remove function. I have the following script which removes the bug. Hope it helps people. :)

http://gist.github.com/589185

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the docs of the [remove function](http://forvar.de/js/mcl/docs.Layer.html#fn-remove) it seems that you should be passing the `itemId` not the the actual item object when calling it.

Comment: there seems an error in the source code for the aforementioned remove method whereby it does not pass the id but a string 'id' instead. reference: http://github.com/Mtillmann/mootools-canvas-lib/blob/master/Source/Layer.js#L42 - just patch this method and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Dimitar Christoff - very good spot. I actually think you should make it it's own answer. You have my upvote if you do.

Comment: @Dimitar - Thanks for confirming what i already suspected :) I did manage to correct it yesterday and it was working. He was referencing a string "a" instead of the object a.id. I think replacing with the following code in the lib works. remove:function(a){this.items.get(a.id).fireEvent("destroy");this.items.erase(a.id)}

Comment: Dimitar hates credit. Its not the first time I have seen him not accepting credit for answering peoples queries! :)