# Not able to download the images?

Tags: android, cursor, android-download-manager

```
  Cursor appu=X.getsomething();

               if (appu.getCount() > 0)
                  {
                   if  (appu.moveToFirst())
                   {
                     do {
                             String uname = appu.getString(appu.getColumnIndex("content_id"));
                             String ax= appu.getString(appu.getColumnIndex("content"));
                             String unknown =url + ax;
                              t1.append("\n");
                               t1.append(unknown);
                               //downloadimages(unknown,uname); 
                        }while (appu.moveToNext());
                   } 
                   X.close();
```

this is my code for getting some result from the database and by this result i am creating a url which has the image and i want to download that image for every cursor result when i try to run the `downloadimages()` function my app crashes always i don't know why ...but when i run the code without it,it runs perfectly.

***downloadimages Method***

```
      public void downloadimages(String url,String filename)
        {
          String ur1=url,v1=filename;
            downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
              Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(ur1);
              DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
              request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
              request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
             request.setDescription("Android Data download using DownloadManager.");
           request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(),Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,v1 + ".jpg");
              downloadManager.enqueue(request);     

        }
```

please tell me what am i doing wrong???

```
 Cursor appu=X.getsomething();

               if (appu.getCount() > 0)
                  {
                   if  (appu.moveToFirst())
                   {
                     do {
                             String uname = appu.getString(appu.getColumnIndex("content_id"));
                             String ax= appu.getString(appu.getColumnIndex("content"));
                             imageid.add(uname);
                             String unknown =url + ax;
                             imagepath.add(unknown);
                             // t1.append("\n");
                               //t1.append(unknown);
                        }while (appu.moveToNext());
                   } 
                   X.close();
                  }}
            this.getitdone();
            }


        public void getitdone()
        {
            int b=imagepath.size();

            for(int i=1;i<=b;i++)
            {
                 String extra=imagepath.get(i).toString();
                 String extra2=imageid.get(i).toString();
                downloadimages(extra,extra2);
            }

        }
```

now i am doing it this way and it is working perfectly

Comment: Is it necessary to add the .jpg to the filename? Should not the mime type of the download do that for you? Just a guess, why don't you debug the application by putting a break function in your downloadimages function?

Comment: i have added the .jpg file extension in the filename look at the second last line in downloadimages function

Comment: thanks guys i have solved it myself sorry to bother you all

Comment: Please post the answer so that people can benefit from what errors you ran into. This is a community wiki and by posting an answer to your question you do help developing the community knowledge base! Cheers.

Comment: Post the answer in the answers sections for consistency and up-votes. I have edited and temporarily posted the answer. Post your update, leave a comment on my answer and I will delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how Pramod resolved the issue:

```
 Cursor appu=X.getsomething();

           if (appu.getCount() > 0)
              {
               if  (appu.moveToFirst())
               {
                 do {
                         String uname = appu.getString(appu.getColumnIndex("content_id"));
                         String ax= appu.getString(appu.getColumnIndex("content"));
                         imageid.add(uname);
                         String unknown =url + ax;
                         imagepath.add(unknown);
                         // t1.append("\n");
                           //t1.append(unknown);
                    }while (appu.moveToNext());
               } 
               X.close();
              }}
        this.getitdone();
        }


    public void getitdone()
    {
        int b=imagepath.size();

        for(int i=1;i<=b;i++)
        {
             String extra=imagepath.get(i).toString();
             String extra2=imageid.get(i).toString();
            downloadimages(extra,extra2);
        }

    }
```

Comment: hey thanks i am new to stackoverflow so i did'nt know i should post it in answers section

Comment: While it's awesome to score free creds on stuff I don't do. Check out how I did it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749880/i-am-able-to-draw-the-box-but-i-am-not-able-to-remove-it-canvas Post your answer so that I can delete this one.