# Function Apps blade blank in Azure Portal (Chrome)

Tags: azureportal

Whenever I try to see the Function Apps blade in the Azure Portal, the info appears for a moment and disappears in a blink. This behavior is only observable in Chrome, works fine with Edge.

I've tried to logoff, clear the cache of my browser and then login again and the problem was still there. I also changed my computer and I am having the same problem. Note that I am logged into Chrome with my Google account.

The Chrome developper console is giving me this error:

{message: "Uncaught Error: Received unexpected message during…e iframe immediately: https://functions.azure.com", fileName: "https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/LAanoyh8NM68.js", lineNumber: 2, columnNumber: 1513}

"Uncaught Error: Received unexpected message during iframe blade load: undefined Disposing the iframe immediately: https://functions.azure.com"

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A quick search of similar issues on StackOverflow yielded this [useful references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597489/properly-disposing-of-browser-resources).
That said, this is probably not the best forum to ask this question since Stackoverflow community is largely reserved for developer-centric questions. Assuming the above doesn't resolve your issue, strongly recommend redirecting your question to the [Azure Management Portal MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-us/home?forum=windowsazuremanagement). Hope this helps.