# Nicest way to manage different levels/scenes in a game with Javascript/HTML5 and EaselJS

Tags: javascript, html, easeljs, createjs

I think I might be looking for the same kind of thing as what this person asked in this thread but it looks like it has not been answered. I won't link the thread, as it has no use to anybody reading this thread AFAIK.

My question is, what is the best way to load different levels/scenes. I am specifically referring to instituting all of the objects that are specific to a scene and then clearing them from memory when you enter a different scene. I want some objects to be able to stay persistent as if the level/scene has not changed and some to be destroyed when there level is no longer being used. For example, you may want to move from the menu screen to the first level or the options screen. I am not really sure when it is best to load textures. I am guessing it depends on how big the textures are.

I am actually writing a game engine, so this is where I will start. Btw, I would also be nice to know how to use it. I have studied the source code of [this project](http://david.blob.core.windows.net/modernhtml5platformer/index.html). And my problem is that I do not quite understand how it works. I am particularly looking at this function.

```
  PlatformerGame.prototype.DownloadAllLevels = function () {
        // Searching where we are currently hosted
        var levelsUrl = window.location.href.replace('index.html', '') + "levels/";
        var that = this;

        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLevels; i++) {
            try {
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open('GET', levelsUrl + i + ".txt", true);
                request.onreadystatechange = makeStoreCallback(i, request, that);
                request.send(null);
            }
            catch (e) {
                // Probably an access denied if you try to run from the file:// context
                // Loading the hard coded error level to have at least something to play with
                //console.log("Error in XHR. Are you offline?"); 
                if (!window.localStorage["platformer_level_0"]) {
                    window.localStorage["platformer_level_0"] = hardcodedErrorTextLevel;
                }
            }
        }
```

Is this loaded from a URL externally or something? Are the levels defined using XML files?

Thanks all

Comment: What that code is doing, is taking a URL like http://mypage.com/index.html, and then loading sequential levels from http://mypage.com/levels/1.txt, http://mypage.com/levels/2.txt, etc. If any of them fail, it saves an error level into your local storage.

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple representation for a level (text, json, ...).
Load it by reading the file, the simplest is to have a relative file (same root url as your game) and make sure you isolate all of the 'destroyable' level data in the same object.
If data is reused across the levels (like sound effects) you can keep this outside of the level specific data to avoid clearing it.
This is how the model looks in terms of scope:

```
browser [
  gameengine [
    yourgame [
      player data (total score ...)
      common resources (sound effects, player graphics, ...)
      level1 specific data (will be unloaded when done)
    ]
  ]
]
```

To load the data you can use PreloadJS.

Concerning unloading read this: [Unloading Resources on HTML with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488866/unloading-resources-on-html-with-javascript)